# Why is `Deref` not implemented on `Cell<T>`?

Tags: rust

Cell is just an in-line-storage/wrapper type that controls mutability/access semantics to the inner type T and provides interior mutability functionality. From the [rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#trait-implementations) `Deref` is NOT implemented for the `Cell<T>` type. Why is this ? An instance of `Cell<T>` is always in a valid state(the memory is always valid and initialized). This means that when implementing `Deref` on `Cell<T>` it cannot possibly panic which is one of the requirements for implementing `Deref`.

Providing a `Deref` impl for `Cell<T>` would have been convenient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

But it would be unsound!

The premise of `Cell` is that it *never* gives out references to its contents (indeed, that's what its brother, `RefCell` does), so all read and write operations on it are atomic<sup>1</sup>.

As part of its implementation, `Cell` has a `set` method with the following signature:

```
fn set(&self, val: T)
```

...which changes the value of `&Cell<T>`, i.e. the value of the cell behind a shared reference<sup>2</sup>. That's how interior mutability works.

Now imagine you could create a reference to the contents of the `Cell`:

```
let cell = Cell::new(1);

let one: &i32 = &*cell;
```

...and someone else called the `set` method:

```
cell.set(2);
```

Now we have mutated the data pointed to by a shared reference (`&T`), which is UB<sup>3</sup>!

```
println!("one = {}", *one); // one = 2 !!!
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb95841fd7d7a63557dc53d229999ebd)

<sub><sup>1</sup>: not in the "threadsafe" sense</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>: it can do this soundly by using an `UnsafeCell`: a compiler builtin that says "trust me compiler, I can enforce borrowing rules, so you don't have to"</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup>: *outside* of an `UnsafeCell` (`&T` doesn't know about the `Cell`)</sub>